# Python : getsize not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to sort the files based on their size and store the log in a file. But I get an error that says 'getsize' not defined. Please help me fix this.

```
from ClientConfig import ClientConfig
import os
import os.path

class VerifyFileNSize:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = ClientConfig()
        self.parseInfo()

    def parseInfo(self):
        count = 0
        size = 0
        sort_file = []
        originalPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.config.Root_Directory_Path())    
        log = open(self.config.File_Count(),'wb')        
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):            
            for f in files:
                sort_file.append(os.path.join(root, f))

        sorted_file = sorted(sort_file, key=getsize)

        for f in sorted_file:
            log.write((str(os.path.getsize(f)) + " Bytes" + "|" + f  +         os.linesep).encode())                
            size += os.path.getsize(f)
            count += 1
        totalPrint = ("Client: Root:" + self.config.Root_Directory_Path() + " Total     Files:" + str(count) + " Total Size in Bytes:" + str(size) + " Total Size in     MB:" + str(round(size /1024/1024, 2))).encode()
        print(totalPrint.decode())
        log.write(totalPrint)
        log.close()
        os.chdir(originalPath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    VerifyFileNSize()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getsize` is not defined in the name space where `sorted` is called. It's a function in module `os.path`, which you imported, so you can refer to it like this:

```
sorted_file = sorted(sort_file, key=os.path.getsize)
```

Another possibility is to do:

```
from os.path import join, getsize
```

or even:

```
from os.path import *
```

that will allow you to do:

```
sorted_file = sorted(sort_file, key=getsize)
```

But the last option is not really recommended, you should try to import only names that you really need.

Answer (score 1):

Try prepending `os.path`:

```
sorted_file = sorted(sort_file, key=os.path.getsize)
                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Alternatively, you could just say `from os.path import getsize`.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason neither of those answers work, there's always:

```
sorted_file = sorted(sort_file, key=lambda x: os.path.getsize(x))
```